# AWS lambda function ConnectionError when configured with VPC

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

*I have an AWS lambda function to trigger daily importer jobs*

I am using a "A starter AWS Lambda function." for this and the lambda_handler is quite simple. 
This is a pseudo code of what I am doing:

```
try:
    cron_job = CloudCron()
    status = redis_get_importer_status(db_key, key)
    if status != 'running': 
        cron_job.login()
        redis_set_importer_status(db_key, key, 'running')
        cron_job.start_importer()
except Exception:
    exc_traceback = traceback.print_exc()
    print(exc_traceback)
```

This function is triggered by a CloudWatch Event every 15 minutes.

The lambda function failed to run the lambda_handler and complained about not having an execution policy for the VPC. To resolve this issue,  I attached AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole Policy for this role. While this ran my lamda_handler, there were other issues. The python requests module threw a ConnectionError when trying to login to the site. 
I increased the timeout to 5 minutes and memory to 1GB and still seeing this issue.

**ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.site.com.au', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/login (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))**

I ran the same lambda_handler within my VPC and seems to be working seamlessly.

**I finally removed the redis set status and get status in my lambda function and the VPC configuration in the lamba and ran the lamda_handler again and this seems to work without any issues.**

I need the VPC configuration to set and get keys from the redis server.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you place the Lambda function inside your VPC it can only access resources inside the VPC. It can't connect to `test.site.com.au` because that resolves to a public IP address outside your VPC. You have a few options to get around this issue:

- Add a NAT Gateway to your VPC. This will provide Internet access to your Lambda function.
- If the site you are trying to access is running on a server inside your VPC, then use the private IP address instead of the DNS name. Alternatively, setup a Route53 private hosted zone in your VPC that resolves that DNS name to the private IP address.

Comment: I have similar issue. and configured private Subnet with NAT Gateway, even so, still have no access to Internet. Any help?

Comment: @Kostanos I already replied to you in another question where you tacked on this exact comment. Please post your own question instead of spamming this comment on every related question.

Comment: Thank you @mark-b I already resolved it. My iisue was that I created NAT gateway inside of private subnet, when I should do it inside public subnet.